# Why is my processor load at 100%

Tags: cpu

It started a month or 2 ago, my HP Stream 11" netbook with Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz × 2 and 3.8 GiB memory running with Ubuntu 16.04LTS suddenly started to slow down considerably. The system monitor shows 100% CPU usage quite often. The time to start is very long also. I did not change my use of the computer. I am trying to understand what is hogging it. How can I test the CPUs? Could the CPUs be spent after 5 years of daily use? Is it a virus?

Comment: Did you check which processes are using the CPU's? That would be valuable information to have a hint about the possible cause. Perhaps it is the time to do a fresh install of a more recent Ubuntu version. 16.04 is past the normal user support period.

Comment: see the command `top` for a processlist